# Create new docker image vs run shell commands

Tags: docker

we are working with [fabric-ca](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-ca) docker image. it does not come with scp installed so we have two options:

Option 1: create a new image as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808396/how-to-create-new-docker-image-based-on-existing-image)

Option 2: install scp from the shell when container is started

we'd like to understand what are the pros and cons of each.

Comment: Close vote? Please, don't. It's a valid question with objective pros and cons for each option, and a lot of people run into this when they start using Docker. Reading answers can save someone hours of doing things the wrong way.

Comment: Reads like it's opinionated to me @AlexPakka.  There are purists and practicalists on both sides of this discussion, and there's no *right* way to do it.  It's more or less what the OP is willing to live with, and we're not in control of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: allows you to build on it further, creates a stable state, you can verify / test an image before releasing

Option 2: takes longer to startup, requires being online during container start, it is harder to trace / understand and manage software stack locked in e.g. bash scripts that start dockers vs. Dockerfile and whatever technology you will end up using for container orchestration.

Ultimately, I use option 2 only for discovery, proof of concept or trying something out. Once I know I need certain container on ongoing basis, I build a proper image via Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider your option 2 a non-starter.  Either build a custom image or use a host directory bind-mount (`docker run -v /host/path:/container/path` option) to inject the data you need; I would probably prefer the bind-mount option.

It’s extremely routine to `docker rm` a container, and when you do, any changes you’ve made locally in a container are lost.  For example, if there is a new software release or a critical security update, you have to recreate the container with a new image.  You should pretty much never install software in an interactive shell in a container, especially if you’re going to use it to copy in data your application needs: you’ll have to repeat this step every single time you delete and recreate the container.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1:

- The `BUILD` of the image is longer, but you execute it only the first time
- The `RUN` is faster
- You don't need an internet connection at `RUN`
- Include a verification of the different steps
- Allow tracability

Option 2:

- The `RUN` is longer
- You need need an internet connection at `RUN`
- Harder to trace